# Invertible positive maps which are not automorphisms

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let  be a unital C*-algebra. Is there a unital positive self-map :→ which is invertible (i.e. injective and surjective) but neither a ∗-automorphism, nor a *-antiautomorphism (i.e. a *-isomorphism with the opposite algebra)? If yes, how does appear its Gelfand-Naimark-Segal covariant representation associated to a state  on  which is invariant under ? Are there examples of such maps which are involutive (i.e. such that ^2=_, or equivalently =^{−1})?

Comment: It is inconsiderate to cross-post without indicating so: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/465894/positive-invertible-maps-which-are-not-automorphisms

Answer (score 3):

$A = \mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{C})$ and $F(X) = X^T$.

Comment: I’m not sure what you meant by the part with GNS representations, but this answers every other question you asked.

Comment: An aside: when $F: A \to A$ is unital, positive, bijective, and involutive (or even just that its inverse is also positive), $F$ do get quite “close” to a $\ast$-automorphism. This is because $F$ is then a linear isometry. It is known that any linear isometry from a $C^\ast$-algebra to itself that preserves the unit is a Jordan $\ast$-automorphism, which is a “blend” between a $\ast$-automorphism and a $\ast$-anti-automorphism. In particular, if $A$ is a von Neumann algebra factor, then $F$ must either be a $\ast$-automorphism or a $\ast$-anti-automorphism.

Comment: I was thinking to exlude also anti-automorphisms, that is *-isomorphisms with the opposite algebra. Many thanks

Comment: @francescofidaleo If you want $F$ to be also involutive, as I already mentioned, $F$ must be a Jordan $\ast$-automorphism, so basically some blend between $\ast$-automorphism and $\ast$-anti-automorphism. For vNa’s, this literally just means a direct sum of a $\ast$-automorphism and a $\ast$-anti-automorphism, so while there are still counterexamples, they are really just boring. Say, $A = M_2 \oplus M_2$ and $T$ is given by the identity map on the first summand and the transpose map on the second.

Comment: @francescofidaleo If you can accept $F$ is not involutive and even that its inverse is not positive, I believe Ozawa in your MathOverflow post already supplied you with a quite general form of counterexamples.

Comment: @francescofidaleo (In case it helps to clarify, the $\varphi$ in Ozawa’s comment on your MathOverflow post indicates a state on $A$.)